# Access velocity variable with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, velocity

```
<head> #set($test = "works")) </head>

<script> 
    var get = "${test}"; // I also tried using '$test' and "$test" also

    alert(get);
</script>
```

And it alerts out **${test}**, but should print **works**.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this...

```
    #set ($test = "works")

  <script type="text/javascript">
       var myvar = "${test}";
       alert (myvar);
  </script>
```

THIS WORKS SURELY!!!!

Comment: I used single quoted, but printed "$test" now. You mean place the velocity code in <head> tags? Still same thing. See my updates question

Answer (score 3):

Try `var get = "$test";` instead of `var get = "${test}";`

Comment: I wish it would work, hehe, but I tried that before and now, it just alerts "$test" now.

Answer (score 1):

I realize the question is old, but this worked for me:

```
#set ($test = "hi")
<script>
    alert("$test");
</script>
```

Need to include quotes around the variable in the alert since it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem while using tiles, the only way i got it to work was to use the jstl c:out tag, like:

```
var get = "<c:out value='${test}' />";
```

that should work, and remember to add the jstl include on the top of the page

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use it as in html:

```
<script> 
    var get = $test;

    alert(get);
</script>
```