# Access Velocity Variable in JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, velocity

In Velocity I set a variable like this:

```
 #at ($page.config)
    #set ($zip = $helper.xssSafeString($url.param("zip")))
 #end
```

Now I want to access the value of `$zip` in a JavaScript file that is included like this:

```
 #at ($page.body)
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/javascript/main.js'></script>
    //...
 #end
```

In the main.js file I alredy tried the following solutions that I found for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290716/access-velocity-variable-with-javascript), but it either detects wrong Syntax or just returns the string "${zip}" as value:

```
var zip = ${zip};
var zip = $zip;
var zip = "${zip}";
```

So my question is how to access the value of the velocity variable and assign in to a JavaScript variable in an external file.

Comment: By "nothing works", what do you mean? What happens exactly? What does appear in the source of the resulting page?

Comment: It detects a wrong Syntax in the first and third case or in the second case (`var zip = "${zip}";`) it just Returns the string "${zip}" as value.
I edited my question to be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Velocity variables are available in velocity templates, you can't use your variables in files that does not go through the template engine. Javascript files does not, unless you specify so.

Since you haven't posted the contents of your `main.js` file I will go for a broader example on how you could make it available in your `main.js`.

Consider the contents of your `main.js` file is:

```
var APP = APP || {};

APP.core = (function () {

    var zip = '';

    return {

        setZip: function(zip) {
            this.zip = zip;
        },

        getZip: function() {
            return this.zip;
        }
    }

})();
```

In your velocity file you can then add the following to set the `zip` variable in `main.js`:

```
#at ($page.body)
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/javascript/main.js'></script>

    <script>
        APP.core.setZip(${zip});
        console.log(APP.core.getZip());
    </script>
#end
```