# How to use velocity variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, string, variables, velocity

I am trying to use a variable from velocity in my external js file. I had a look also at [Access Velocity Variable in JavaScript File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40042449/access-velocity-variable-in-javascript-file) but that helped me only use it in js only if it is written in the .vm file.

My velocity:

```
 #set ($testvar= "#include('templates/some.txt')")
 <script type="text/javascript">
    #include("templates/currencyDetail.js")
    var myvar = "${testvar}";    
    </script>

    <body>
        <div class="myConfluenceMacro">
            <fieldset class="parameters hidden">
                <input type="hidden" class="dayDates" value= myvar>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </body>
```

MY JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".myConfluenceMacro").each(function(){

            var dayDates = $(this).find("input.dayDates").val();

            $(this).html("Hello <b>world!</b>" + dayDates );
        });
    });
```

When I print it out, I get only

> $!{testvar}

as output, but not the value of my value... Does it have to be a json or can I send a string that I have read from the .txt file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to set your velocity `variable` directly as a `value` of your `input`, using `value="$testvar"`.

This is how should be your template code:

```
#set ($testvar= "#include('templates/some.txt')")
<body>
    <div class="myConfluenceMacro">
        <fieldset class="parameters hidden">
            <input type="hidden" class="dayDates" value="$testvar">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</body>
```

In your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var dayDates = $("input.dayDates")[0].value;
        $(this).html("Hello <b>world!</b> " + dayDates );
});
```

You can take a look at [Velocity **Reference Miscellany** docs](http://people.apache.org/~henning/velocity/html/ch04s05.html) for further details.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it out now

Comment: How should I get it on the javascript site?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myConfluenceMacro").each(function(){

  
   
   var dayDates = document.getElementById("dayDates").value; 
     $(this).html("Hello <b>world!</b>" + dayDates );
    });
});

Comment: @TeslaX But you haven't defined an `id` for the input here, use `var dayDates = document.querySelector("input.dayDates").value;` to get it.

Comment: Sorry again. I used: var dayDates = document.querySelector("input.dayDates").value; and as output  $(this).html("Hello <b>world!</b>" + dayDates ); but I get the error msg: SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break

Comment: For some reason, the string was the problem... I put now only "HELLOWORLD" inside an it works.... thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Great, glad it helps.